# Make a hash table using smart pointers?

Tags: c++, vector, hashtable, smart-pointers

I'm trying to make a hashtable by using smart pointers, but I'm not sure if I am doing it right. I've been trying to play with two combinations of them, but I am afraid I don't know how to initialize the table to be empty? Maybe that is the wrong verbage, but I am stuck and I need to be pointed in the right direction.

My hashNode:

```
struct{
    hashNode(int k, std::string i) : key(k), item(i){};

    int key;
    std::string item;
}
```

My hashtable:

```
class Hashtable
{
public:

    Hashtable(); //not sure how to build the constructor build an empty table.

    int hashFunction(int key);
    int find(int key);
    void insert(int key, std::string item);
    void remove(int key);

private:

    int tableSize = 10;
    std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<hashNode>> hashTable;
    //std::vector<std::shared_ptr<hashNode>> hashTable;
};
```

I am stuck here, as I don't know if I am implementing my hashTable correctly or not. Or, if this is just a bad idea to go with. Any advice would do.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<hashNode>>` you certainly don't want that.

Comment: Careful with shared pointers. They are rarely what you want unless you truly do have an object with multiple owners. If only one user is responsible for deleting the pointer, you want a `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Okay, say I'm trying to replicate `hashNode **hashtable` like I have seen in other examples. Is it not the same thing? I guess this is where I am getting confused. Is implementing the vector more correct? @GuillaumeRacicot

Comment: No need for pointers at all if you do it right. All you should need is a vector of vector (`std::vector<std::vector<hashNode>>`).

Comment: @user4581301 this was my next idea that I was going to use, in my constructor then, would I just use a for loop to initialize an empty table of size 10?

Comment: @Sailanarmo unique pointer are better, but have a different syntax when it's pointing to an array. Shared pointer don't support arrays. Refer to the documentation.

Comment: assuming `std::vector<std::vector<hashNode>> hashTable;` `hashTable(10)` in the member initializer list should do the trick: `Hashtable(): hashTable(10) {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `hashNode` attribute member to be a single pointer using `std::unique_ptr`. Then, in HashTable's constructor you can initialise it with `std::make_unique`.

In you **HashTable.h**

```
class Hashtable {
public:
   Hashtable(); 

   int hashFunction(int key);
   int find(int key);
   void insert(int key, std::string item);
   void remove(int key);

private:
   int tableSize = 10;
   std::unique_ptr<hashNode[]> hashTable;  // As stated in the comments.
};
```

In your **HashTable.cpp**

```
Hashtable::Hashtable() {
   hashTable = std::make_unique<hashNode[10]>();
}
```

Comment: I guess I need to look further in the documentation as I have been given a short brief introduction to smart pointers and have only used them in Trees.  But what is the difference between the two?

Comment: `make_unique<hashNode[tableSize]>` shouldn't be legal if tableSize is not a constant.

Comment: @immibis, should I make it a constant if it's only going to make the initial table of size 10? I will rehash it when it gets half full, so I left it as a non constant for the purpose of rehashing. But when I make a new table, the tablesize would then change to 20. So wouldn't that be an issue?

Comment: Two points: 1) If the array is of fixed size, why bother dynamically allocating at all? 2) Consider using the Member Initializer List. Save you a few cycles initializing the `unique_ptr` to null if the first thing you're going to do with it is assign it a value.

Comment: OK. Point 1 got knocked off the list.

Comment: @user4581301 I tried implementing this method and I got an error, "use of deleted function"

Comment: @Sailanarmo Ha! Just bringing this up in my answer. Odds are somewhere your HashTable is being copied and you can't copy a `unique_ptr` because, well, it's unique, right? You will have to force the Rule of Five and provide a move constructor and move assignment and probably delete the copy constructor and assignment operator.

Comment: @user4581301 haha okay, I think I remember something about those in one of my classes a few semesters ago. I'll have to look into that and see how far I can get, thank you very much for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Example of HashTable with containers

```
class Hashtable
{
public:
    Hashtable(): hashTable(10) // initial size set here
    {
        // does nothing
    }
    int hashFunction(int key);
    int find(int key);
    void insert(int key, std::string item); // this gets a bit more complicated
                                            // due to copying during rehash
    void remove(int key);

private:
    std::vector<std::vector<hashNode>> hashTable; // vector knows its size 
};
```

This slightly complicates the rehashing as now you have to copy instead of moving pointers around, but on the upside there are zero memory management woes or difficulties with copying something that contains a `unique_ptr`. It wouldn't be unique if you copied it, would it?